# This code of android app runs once only and app stops working

Tags: java, android, stack

This is a code for stack;
on clicking push button number is added into stack and pushed is displayed on textview, similarly on clicking push number is pushed from stack. but only one time operation is done or alternately, I cant push twice.

```
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etn1);
     x =  e1.getId();
```

// Event Listener on Click

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvn);

      if (v.getId()== R.id.btn1) {
         Stack s1 = new Stack();
          s1.push(x);
          EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etn1);
          e1.setId(0);

          t1.setText("Pushed");
          t1.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
      }
      else if (v.getId() == R.id.btn2) {
          Stack s2 = new Stack();
          s2.pop();
          t1.setText("Poped");
          t1.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, 
          android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
      }
    }
```

Comment: you will help us if you gave us the stack trace

Comment: initialise views inside onCreateMethod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are getting `NullPointerException` at `s2.pop()`. You are trying to `pop` an `null` object as there is no `object` in your stack `s2`.

**1.** Try using a single `Stack` and declare it as `global` and use it for both `push` and `pop` operation.

**2.** Before any `pop` operation check weather the `stack` is `empty` or not.

**Try this:**

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ........
    ................

    Stack stack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ........
        ................

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etn1);

        // Stack
        stack = new Stack();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvn);

        // Get id
        x =  e1.getId();

        if (v.getId()== R.id.btn1) {

            // Push
            stack.push(x);

            EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etn1);
            e1.setId(0);

            t1.setText("Pushed");
            t1.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.btn2) {

            if (stack.empty()) {
                // Show message
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stack is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Pop
                stack.pop();

                t1.setText("Poped");
               t1.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Glad to know that. If my answer helps please mark this answer as right answer by clicking on tick mark. Thanks in advance :) Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers